# Pushing array of values from a form into Google Spreadsheet comes through as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a form with text fields which the user can "Add New" by clicking a button. These fields share the same name. I'm trying pass the values into Google Spreadsheets, but the values all come through as 'undefined' with the following code, even though console.log prints the answers as strings which look okay to me.

So if the user for example submits 3 separate entries for SUNDAY_NOTES[], all 3 strings should end up in one cell broken up by new lines, but instead I'm just getting "undefined".

```
<form action="" method="post" id="timesheet">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]"> // the user can create multiples of these ^ for each day of the week

  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $form = $('form#timesheet'),
  url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf45XRaA/exec'

  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $form.serializeArray().map((e) => {
         return e.value
        }).join('\n')
    });

  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have an error in your code, `.join('\n');` should not end up with an "**;**".

Comment: confirming the error cata john mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. In the snippet below I am storing the data split by `\n` in a variable and logging it. You can check the output.

Although your JS is correct, I suspect that you actually want to be using a different HTTP method. Perhaps `POST` or `PUT`? I can't be specific as you have not said which API endpoint you are using.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $form = $('form#timesheet'),
  url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf45XRaA/exec'

  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $form.serializeArray().map((e) => {
      return e.value
    }).join('\n');
    console.log(data);
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: data
    }).done(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus) => {
      console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="timesheet">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES[]">

  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my Spreadsheet, each values are "undefined"- even for unique text inputs fields (not arrays like shown above).  And if I remove the .map((e)... function, the values come through correctly, but only the first entry gets posted to the cell.

Comment: @Jake Then the issue is with how you are using the API. What is the URL for the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

remove the `[]` from your input's name as this is needed if you want to receive an array in the server side, then create a function that groups the values according to the inouts' keys :

```
function group(arr) {
  var tempArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(e) {
    var tempObj = tempArr.find(function(a) { return a.name == e.name });
    if (!tempObj)
      tempArr.push(e)
    else
      tempArr[tempArr.indexOf(tempObj)].value += ', ' + e.value;
  });

  return tempArr;
}
```

and use it like :

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: group($form.serializeArray()),
   //... rest of your code
```

this will keep the original structure that works,

here's a snippet :

```js
var $form = $('form#timesheet');

function group(arr) {
  var tempArr = [];
  arr.forEach(function(e) {
    var tempObj = tempArr.find(function(a) { return a.name == e.name });
    if (!tempObj)
      tempArr.push(e)
    else
      tempArr[tempArr.indexOf(tempObj)].value += ', ' + e.value;
  });

  return tempArr;
}

$form.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var grouped = group($form.serializeArray());
  console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="timesheet">
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES"><br />
  <input type="text" name="SUNDAY_NOTES"> // user can click a button to keep adding more SUNDAY_NOTES fields

  <input type="text" name="MONDAY_NOTES"> // and so forth

  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```